# Sort and Filter an Object that has numbers in its property names

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, sorting

I am trying to filter out items that has the `mode` set to `null`, however, after adding this `filter`, *all items disappear*, even if they do not have the `mode` prop at `null`.

```js
const filteredAndSortedBotConfigs = Object.keys(botConfigs)
  .sort((a, b) => {
    return parseInt(a, 10) - parseInt(b, 10);
  })
  .filter(this.filterConfigsByBot)
  .filter(this.filterConfigsByStatus)
  .filter((item) => item.mode === null);
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the functions `filterConfigsByBot` and `filterConfigsByStatus`? That would probably help us debug

Comment: You state `I am trying to filter out items that has the "mode" props set to null` but your code does the opposite, only allowing modes that are `null`. Additionally, there are 2 other filter functions you haven't shown so we aren't sure what those are doing. Looks like this either needs to be closed as a simple typo or more info needs to be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `botConfig` data is *object with numbers as properties*:

```js
const botConfigs = {
  2: { mode: null, botId: "10", status: "ACTIVE", },
  1: { mode: "A", botId: "20", status: "ACTIVE", },
  3: { mode: "C", botId: "15", status: "STOPPED", },
};
```

And you want to *sort* by (number) properties and then *filter* on properties of values. So, this is how your filters functions might look like:

```
filterConfigsByBot = (key) => {
  return botConfigs[key].botId !== "0"; // assuming botConfigs is available in scope
};

filterConfigsByStatus = (key) => {
  return botConfigs[key].status !== "STOPPED";
};
```

Also, remember to `map` keys to values of `botConfigs` at the end (if needed):

```
const filteredAndSortedBotConfigs = Object.keys(botConfigs)
    .sort((a, b) => parseInt(a, 10) - parseInt(b, 10))
    .filter(this.filterConfigsByBot)
    .filter(this.filterConfigsByStatus)
    .filter((key) => botConfigs[key].mode !== null) // to filter out items that has the `mode` set to `null`
    .map((key) => botConfigs[key]);
```

PS: You can combine the three filters into a single filter callback.

#### Edit:

Simplified version using a [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
const filteredAndSortedBotConfigs = Object.keys(botConfigs)
    .sort((a, b) => parseInt(a, 10) - parseInt(b, 10))
    .reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (
        botConfigs[curr].botId !== "0" &&
        botConfigs[curr].status !== "STOPPED" &&
        botConfigs[curr].mode !== null
    ) {
        acc.push(botConfigs[curr]); // pushing values, not keys
    }
    return acc;
    }, []);
```

Comment: > "Assuming that botConfig data is object with numbers as properties" 

Object keys are strings.

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan Feel free to edit my answers if you see such confusing remarks. I would appreciate your efforts. + It might give you [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/223/copy-editor).