# Sort object items by the dateModified prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, object

I  was just trying to see how I can sort the items from **newest to oldest** in an object based on the `dateModified` prop.

I have tried doing the good old fashion way of sorting, however, the items still render in the same order no matter what. Is there any other way to do so other than this way?

**Object:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
const filteredAndSortedBotConfigs = Object.keys(botConfigs)
  .sort((a, b) => new Date(b.modifiedTimestamp) - new Date(a.modifiedTimestamp))
  .filter(this.filterConfigsByBot)
  .filter(
    (key) =>
      botConfigs[key].status === "RUNNING" && botConfigs[key].mode !== null
  );
```

Comment: Can you share more details about the problem and share a JSON example of your object maybe?

Comment: While this might seem like a silly idea, are you 100% sure you're using the order of that array and not, say, doing `Object.keys(botConfigs)` again? The code above looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

[Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) by date is [simple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10123953/2873538):

```js
arr.sort((a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b));
// Or
arr.sort((a, b) => new Date(a).getTime() - new Date(b).getTime());
```

In your code, `a` and `b` are *keys* (properties).

So, you need to use `botConfigs[key].modifiedTimestamp` to read the timestamp:

```
const filteredAndSortedBotConfigs = Object.keys(botConfigs)
  .sort(
    (a, b) =>
      new Date(botConfigs[a].modifiedTimestamp) -
      new Date(botConfigs[b].modifiedTimestamp)
  )
  .filter(this.filterConfigsByBot)
  .filter(
    (key) =>
      botConfigs[key].status === "RUNNING" && botConfigs[key].mode !== null
  );
```

#### Edit:

You are looking for "newest to oldest" i.e. descending order, so you just need to reverse the sign.

- `a - b` will sort in **ascending** order
- `b - a` will sort in **descending** order

Comment: A minor thing - Can you add the missing space in `newDate` so it reads `new Date`?

Comment: The code will only return the sorted keys. You should use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the sorted objects.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. OP [knows about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66937698/2873538). It is good that you posted your answer as a reminder.

Comment: Aha. Interesting. Thanks for sharing the link.

Answer (score 0):

The date sorting logic is referencing the `modifiedTimestamp` property of the keys which are strings instead of the bot config objects (`a.modifiedTimestamp` and `b.modifiedTimestamp` are both `undefined`). Even after fixing it, you would only get the sorted keys and you have to use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the sorted array of configs which I imagine is what you want.

You can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get an array of configs, apply the filters and then sort them by the `modifiedTimestamp` property.

```
const filteredAndSortedBotConfigs = Object.values(botConfigs)
  .filter(this.filterConfigsByBot)
  .filter((config) => config.status === 'RUNNING' && config.mode !== null)
  .sort((a, b) => new Date(b.modifiedTimestamp) - new Date(a.modifiedTimestamp))
```

You should also update `this.filterConfigsByBot` since it receives the bot config object and not the key anymore.

```
filterConfigsByBot = (config) => {
  const { botId } = config
  // return a boolean based on the `botId` value
}
```